# Issue In Getting Child Row of the Listview On Swipe

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe

I am trying to retrieve the Child Row of the listview when the event swipe take place.I have created a BaseAdapter which sets a customView following is the GetView Method of BaseAdapter:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ModelView modelView = null;

    ModelClass model=modelList.get(position);
    if(convertView==null)
    {

        modelView=new ModelView(context,model);

    }
    else{
        Log.d("convertView","NotNUll");
        modelView=(modelView) convertView;

    }
    modelView.setModel(diet);


    return modelView;       
}
```

My ModelView Class Looks Like this:

```
public class ModelView extends LinearLayout {
Context context;
TextView text1,text2,text3;
ImageView img1;
Model d;
public ModelView(Context context,Model d) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
    this.d=d;
    this.setTag(d);
    HookUp();

}

public void HookUp() {

    this.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay, null);

    this.addView(view);

    textDietHeadLine=(TextView) view.findViewById(R);
    text=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    text=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

}
```

}

In My Main Activity on TouchListener when i am retrieving the Tag it  always give me null,i dont know where i m going wrong...any help would be appreciated ,although i searched alot on this issue but it was of no avail,i am a beginner in android,and struck on this for quiet a while now,plss  helppp :(

Following is the touchListener Code:

```
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
     {
         if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){

            // Log.d("Diet d","v.gettag()); 

             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
```

Comment: what is onTouch part of?

Comment: class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener
  {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
      {
          if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                    
           Log.d("Model d",""+v.getTag());     
           
              return true;
          }else{
              return false;
          }
      }

Comment: have you tried setItemClick event, or you want to get the ModelView which the finger holding on?

Comment: @VinceStyling:Exactly i want the modelview class so that i can change that row contents and get to know on which row did the swipe took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It a bit complicated, I hope i can do it right, in case you want to get particular row which user swiping on, it need to extracting a method which carry deep in ListView calls [findMotionRow](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.findMotionRow%28int%29), this method declare as an actually **private** visibility for extender, so we must make that method available in our own ListView and learn how to invoke it from the ListView's source code :

```
public class YourListView extends ListView {
    ...Constructors...

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mMotionPosition = findMotionRow(ev.getY());
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private int mMotionPosition;

    public int getMotionPosition() {
        return mMotionPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Find which position is motion on.
     * Note : this method copy into public from 4.0 source code.
     * @param y Y coordinate of the motion event.
     * @return Selected index (starting at 0) of the data item.
     */
    private int findMotionRow(float y) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        if (childCount > 0) {
            if (!isStackFromBottom()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    View v = getChildAt(i);
                    if (y <= v.getBottom()) {
                        return getFirstVisiblePosition() + i;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = childCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    View v = getChildAt(i);
                    if (y >= v.getTop()) {
                        return getFirstVisiblePosition() + i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return INVALID_POSITION;
    }
}
```

In the proper place, i.e Activity.onCreate(), we can listening the onTouch event and able to use `mMotionPosition` to take the row's View :

```
mYourListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int hoverChildIndex =
            mYourListView.getMotionPosition() - mYourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        ModelView hoveringView = (ModelView) mYourListView.getChildAt(hoverChildIndex);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Bingooo...U just hit Bull's Eye..THnakuuu SO so much,i was struck on this issue from quiet a while now,and it was frustrating..thanku so much :)
It was great Learning curve,i would definitely keep that in mind..COngo!!

Comment: my pleasure, I'm gladly that i can help you.